# ¿Cómo usar RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo un conjunto de carpetas que tienen varios archivos. El nombre de las carpetas es un número y dentro de ellas hay varios archivos en PDF con nombres como DocumentoIdentidad, LicenciaConducccion, Pasaporte. S

Answer (score 1):

Vale!

Espero haber entendido tu petición, y ojalá te sirva lo siguiente:

```
# Definimos el directorio donde se encuentran todas las subcarpetas
# (hay que reemplazar la cadena de "directorio" por la ruta que tú uses)
directorio <- "C:\\Users\\Vale\\Desktop\\prueba"

# Creamos un vector con las rutas completas de los archivos originales con extensión pdf
archivos_originales_rutas_completas <- dir(path = directorio, pattern = "\\.pdf$", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)

# Creamos un vector con la ruta padre de cada uno de los archivos
archivos_rutas_padre <- dirname(path = dir(path = directorio, pattern = "\\.pdf$", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE))

# Creamos un vector con los nombres individuales de los archivos
archivos_nombres <- basename(path = dir(path = directorio, pattern = "\\.pdf$", recursive = TRUE, full.names = FALSE))

# Creamos un vector con los nombres individuales de las rutas padre,
# que nos servirán como prefijos de los nuevos nombres de archivo
nombres_nuevos_prefijos <- dirname(path = dir(path = directorio, pattern = "\\.pdf$", recursive = TRUE, full.names = FALSE))

# Recurriendo a dplyr, creamos un vector con los sufijos de los
# nuevos nombres, dependiendo del nombre de los archivos
nombres_nuevos_sufijos <- dplyr::case_when(
  archivos_nombres == "DocumentoIdentidad.pdf" ~ "01",
  archivos_nombres == "LicenciaConducción.pdf" ~ "02",
  archivos_nombres == "Pasaporte.pdf" ~ "03"
)

# Creamos un vector con las rutas completas de los archivos renombrados
archivos_renombrados_rutas_completas <- file.path(archivos_rutas_padre, paste0(nombres_nuevos_prefijos, "_", nombres_nuevos_sufijos, ".pdf"))

# Renombramos los archivos
file.rename(from = archivos_originales_rutas_completas, to = archivos_renombrados_rutas_completas)
```